# Book: Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming, 2nd Edn; Chapter 2 - Working with 3D Robot Modeling in ROS

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am facing a problem in running tutorials given in the book: Mastering ROS in Robotic Programming, Chapter 2.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS Kinetic. In particular, when I run my launch file as

```
khan@khan:~/catkin_ws/src/mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg/launch$ roslaunch mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg view_arm.launch
```

The following error occurs.

```
unknown macro name: xacro:base 
XacroException(u'unknown macro name: xacro:base',)
```

I have checked the file again and again and there is nothing I changed. It is the tutorial files. I don't know why it is not running. Please, suggest any help. Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242044/book:-mastering-ros-for-robotics-programming,-2nd-edn;-chapter-2----working-with-3d-robot-modeling-in-ros/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-20**:
If [this](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros) is the code you are referring to, then the readme explicitly states that:

> The code is comaptible with ROS Jade and ROS Indigo

so it could well be that something doesn't work in Kinetic.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-08-30**:
I have tried to run this file for ROS Indigo as well. I got the same error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-31**:
I would suggest reporting this issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/issues) of `qboticslabs/mastering_ros`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Dr Abdul Mannan

Maybe I know your problem. According to your terminal's warning informations, I think you use the distribution of ROS is Jade or Kinetic, and the problem is just on the distribution of ROS. Firstly, I am using the Indigo, and I use the following command no any problem.

```
$> roslaunch mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg view_arm.launch
```

So according to your error information, I find the following lines in the **seven_dof_arm.xacro**:

[image: screenshot from 2016-09-08 20 46 18]

As mentioned by error, I also don't find the definition of macro **base**. For example, if you are coding by using C++, you need call a function, but the function is not defined and implemented yet, the compiler must report a error. So solution is commenting out these lines:

[image: screenshot from 2016-09-08 21 11 28]

As for why indigo can run, I think  the checked mechanism of indigo's **xacro** is less than Jade or Kinetic.

In addition to the error, there are warning informations on the terminal. If you visit [Xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) wiki, you can find the **xacro** of Jade or Kinetic has more enhanced functionality and more limits than that of Indigo. So for the cause of warning, you can get by running xacro with option **--check-order** on the terminal just like

```
 $> roscd mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg
 $> rosrun xacro xacro.py --check-order urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro
```

Last, according to the warning informations, I think the solution is here: [Deprecated Syntax](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Deprecated_Syntax)

---

Originally posted by [myyerol](https://answers.ros.org/users/21250/myyerol/) with karma: 36 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-09-08**:
Thank you so much myyerol for you response. That was so long waited problem. You have no idea how much you helped me. I owe you. I am coming to Tsinghua University for post doctorate. I shall be happy to catch you up there. Once again thank you so much.